# Hausdorff Dimension Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, hausdorff-measure

What are some examples of non-trivial metric spaces that have Hausdorff Dimension of infinity?

I could only think of $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric.

Comment: [This frequent Mathematics Stack Exchange user's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21361/mark-mcclure) [Ph.D. dissertation](https://www.marksmath.org/scholarship/dissertation.pdf) is a good place to look. (Hope he doesn't mind my pointing this out!)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro No problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the separable Hilbert space of infinite dimension 
$$
\ell^2=\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R}:\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n^2<\infty\}
$$

Comment: +1 Did you know that the subset of $\ell^2$ with all rational coordinates has Hausdorff dimension 1? One of my [favorite results of Erdos](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1940-11.pdf).

Comment: No, I never studied the Hausdorff measure in depth. It's an interesting result, thanks for share it!